# iOS: how to perform a HTTP POST request?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm approaching iOS development and I'd like to have one of my first applications to perform a HTTP POST request.

As far as I can understand, I should manage the connection which handles the request via a `NSURLConnection` object, which forces me to have a delegate object, which in turn will handle data events.

Could someone please clarify the task with a practical example?

I should contact an https endpoint sending authentication data (username and password) and getting back a plain text response.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use NSURLConnection as follows:

1. **Set your `NSURLRequest`: Use `requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL` to initialise the request.**

   If you need to specify a POST request and/or HTTP headers, use `NSMutableURLRequest` with

   - `(void)setHTTPMethod:(NSString *)method`
   - `(void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data`
   - `(void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field`
2. **Send your request in 2 ways using `NSURLConnection`:**

   - Synchronously: `(NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error`

     This returns a `NSData` variable that you can process.

     IMPORTANT: Remember to kick off the synchronous request in a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI.
   - Asynchronously: `(void)start`

Don't forget to set your NSURLConnection's delegate to handle the connection as follows:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.data setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
    [self.data appendData:d];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                 message:[error localizedDescription]
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"") 
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Do anything you want with it 

    [responseText release];
}

// Handle basic authentication challenge if needed
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSString *username = @"username";
    NSString *password = @"password";

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                             password:password
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: Apple says that using synchronous requests is "not recommended" http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html  although if you know enough to mess around with different threads, you'll probably be fine.

Comment: @Anh Nice Answer, but I was a little skeptical with the last method `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`. Are there any security issues with hard-coding passwords / usernames? Is there any way around this?

Comment: Generally you would store the credentials in the keychain and retrieve them there to handle Basic-Auth.

Comment: iOS 5 onwards can also use + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT: ASIHTTPRequest has been abandoned by the developer. It's still really good IMO, but you should probably look elsewhere now.**

I'd highly recommend using the [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) if you are handling HTTPS. Even without https it provides a really nice wrapper for stuff like this and whilst it's not hard to do yourself over plain http, I just think the library is nice and a great way to get started.

The HTTPS complications are far from trivial in various scenarios, and if you want to be robust in handling all the variations, you'll find the ASI library a real help.

Comment: The ASIHTTPRequest library has been officially abandoned by it's developer as this post states: http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release]; ,I would recommend you to use other libraries as the developer suggests, or even better, try to learn NSURLRequest :)

Cheers.

Comment: @Mr.Gando - your link doesn't seem to work - note that the semi-colon is significant. That said, VERY sad to see it abandoned. It does lots of the authentication stuff really nicely and it's a lot of work to replicate it all ... shame ...

Comment: And that link also doesn't work. For anyone trying to find it, please note the correct url requires a semi-colon on the end of it - SO is causing the ; to be excluded from the links people are posting.

Comment: [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) is what most people seem to be using now.

Answer (score 7):

I thought I would update this post a bit and say that alot of the iOS community has moved over to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) after `ASIHTTPRequest` was abandoned. I highly recommend it. It's a great wrapper around `NSURLConnection` and allows for asynchronous calls, and basically anything you might need.

Comment: I know the accepted answer is good, don't mean to demeanor or anything, but  this should definitely have more upvotes. Perhaps if an example and some code fragment is added, as the question suggests?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an updated answer for iOS7+. It uses NSURLSession, the new hotness. Disclaimer, this is untested and was written in a text field:

```
- (void)post {
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/dontposthere"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    // Uncomment the following two lines if you're using JSON like I imagine many people are (the person who is asking specified plain text)
    // [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    // [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(    NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

Or better yet, use AFNetworking 2.0+. Usually I would subclass AFHTTPSessionManager, but I'm putting this all in one method to have a concise example.

```
- (void)post {
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com"]];
    // Many people will probably want [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    // Many people will probably want [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = NO; // Some servers require this to be YES, but default is NO.
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
    [[manager POST:@"dontposthere" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"darn it");
    }] resume];
}
```

If you are using the JSON response serializer, the responseObject will be object from the JSON response (often NSDictionary or NSArray).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Pure Swift 3 (Xcode 8) example:**
Please try out the following sample code. It is the simple example of `dataTask` function of `URLSession`.

```
func simpleDataRequest() {

        //Get the url from url string
        let url:URL = URL(string: "YOUR URL STRING")!

        //Get the session instance
        let session = URLSession.shared

        //Create Mutable url request
        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

        //Set the http method type
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //Set the cache policy
        request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        //Post parameter
        let paramString = "key=value"

        //Set the post param as the request body
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data as Data?, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                //Oops! Error occured.
                print("error")
                return
            }

            //Get the raw response string
            let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))

            //Print the response
            print(dataString!)

        }

        //resume the task
        task.resume()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0***

**Using URLSession:**

```
 let url = URL(string:"Download URL")!
 let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)
 let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
 let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

 let task : URLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: req as URLRequest)
task.resume()
```

URLSession Delegate call:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

}


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten writ: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite exp: Int64) {
                   print("downloaded \(100*writ/exp)" as AnyObject)

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

}
```

**Using Block GET/POST/PUT/DELETE:**

```
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "Your API URL here" ,param: param))!,
        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
        timeoutInterval:"Your request timeout time in Seconds")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers as? [String : String] 

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {data,response,error in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if (error != nil) {
         print(error)
         } else {
         print(httpResponse)
         }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           //Update your UI here
        }

    }
    dataTask.resume()
```

Working fine for me.. try it 100% result guarantee

Answer (score 0):

Here is how POST HTTP request works for iOS 8+ using NSURLSession:

```
- (void)call_PostNetworkingAPI:(NSURL *)url withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(id object,NSError *error,NSURLResponse *response))completion
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
    config.URLCache = nil;
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5.0f;
    config.timeoutIntervalForResource =10.0f;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *Req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [Req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:Req completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error == nil) {

            NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            if (dict != nil) {
                completion(dict,error,response);
            }
        }else
        {
            completion(nil,error,response);
        }
    }];
    [task resume];

}
```

Hope this will satisfy your following requirement.