# Automatic email from iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have seen some similar questions here on stack-overflow, but in my application i want when user click on confirm button automatic email go to the email id specified in the form with other details.

How can i implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make a post request to a server and have the server then send the email.

Comment: can you explain it in detail Please

Comment: Just send the message, from field, to field and perhaps subject directly to your server and it can send out the email to the recipients, by making an http post request.  You may want some sort of security on the webserver, but that is a detail at best.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. If you know any can you send me link of example code or tutorial or something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send emails automatically without sending the user to the mail application.  You could however, take advantage of a third party service like Amazon Simple Email Service http://aws.amazon.com/ses/ to send the message.

Comment: Nope. The MFMailComposeViewController class provides a way to send emails in-app, though not automatically.

Comment: Did you just read your own response? It doesn't send it automatically, but that is exactly what the user requested.  Please take time to read and understand the question before down-voting.

Comment: Read and understood the question; the downvote was for the inaccuracy of the first part of your answer. Sending the user to the Mail application won’t send the email automatically either.