# Converting Objects to plist file then to data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml

I have an array of objects that consist of several strings, I need to push these up to a web service as XML data.  What are the steps involved here?  As far as I know I need to convert the objects to a plist file, then convert this file to NSData (?)  I can't find anything online that really lays it out..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is JSON.  [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) is very common and simple to use.

It's a two-liner to get a json string from your array.  Then you'll create an NSURLRequest that represents the post and an NSURLConnection that performs the request.  Lot's of resources for that on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request) and [elsewhere](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://homepage.mac.com/jimbokun/Excelsior.html) or [this](https://gist.github.com/yfactorial/objectivesupport/tree/master/Classes/lib/Serialization). I doubt plist files are what you want. All you need is to serialize your object into the xml format your web service requires.