# Post image to a webform in drupal 7 from iOS application using rest services

Tags: ios, swift, webforms, drupal-7

I'm trying to post in webform from my IOS application via services in drupal. Im can succesfully post the webform but the image I'm trying to send is not getting shown in the website results.

Hence, I need to know how an image need to be posted along with other textfields in WebForm.

Since the field used for uploading image in webform is File Type.As Image field is not available in drupal module for webform from my research.

Any help regarding posting of image along with other textfields using iOS application in webform would be appreciated.

I have been in deadlock with this issue for past few days.

Comment: So, you're trying to post image to your server? If so, it already has several answers in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434537/post-image-to-server-in-iphone. Let me know if it's anything else

Comment: it is for webform not normal node...need to be submitted using submissions. Posting file type field is causing the issue from the question