# Sending NSString to PHP script

Tags: cocoa-touch

How can I send an `NSString` from the iPhone to a remote php script?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://host.com/script.php?text=This+is+some+text";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSLog(@"The server responded: %@", response);
```

Comment: Be sure to encode the parameter, otherwise any invalid-char in your string will cause an invalid URL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088473/url-encode-a-nsstring

Comment: Also note that an URL got a limited length accepted by servers, so be sure your parameter/string is not to long.

Comment: it's a better solution to send data/strings as a POST-request. More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request . At server-side, you can access the objects with $_POST['key']

Comment: @JelleDeLaender it may be better (less prone to hit GET-parameter limitations) but then again, it is far more complicated.