# How can we use WCF services from iPhone?

Tags: wcf, ios4

I am implementing an application that displays data which is coming from a back end server. The back end server is using WCF for writing web services. I am not familiar with that WCF.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Do you need to implement the WCF services and enpdoints or do you just need to consume them?

Comment: @MichaelDelano I just need to consume the service. I need to call the service and get the data from the service. Could you please let me know how can I call the service?

Answer (score 1):

If your WCF application is configured to be a SOAP service, then any SOAP libraries for iOS can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can make HTTP or SOAP requests to WCF. Given an HTTP request, for example, you could test it using cUrl. In it's simplest form, a cUrl get request is as follows:

```
curl http://stackoverflow.com
```

You very well may need to make POST or PUT request. If so you can review the docs here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html. I've included an example POST request using cUrl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d <YOUR PAYLOAD HERE> http://stackoverflow/fakepost
```

There a loads of ways to make HTTP requests, cUrl is just a client for doing so.

The following describes an iOS implementation of a POST request: [iOS: how to perform a HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request) .