# How to create NameValuePair list in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsarray, nsdictionary, keyvaluepair

I am new in ios. I am working in a application in which i need to post some data in nameValuepair so I used NSDictionary to crate a name value pair but with NSDictionary there is issue on server side to parse posted data. Is there any way to create NameValuePair in iOS 6 like in android there is a entity called BasicNameValuePair .

Comment: what you want pass here?

Comment: I need to post something like :- [id=2315645, name=Ram, deviceId=3453564666643634]

Comment: You can also use JSON in iOS, here is an example of it,http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
   NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourURLaddress"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:Url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *MyConnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                                 delegate:self];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = @"id=2315645&name=Ram&deviceId=3453564666643634";
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [MyConnection start];
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Actualy in android version of same application data is posted in the form of BasicNameValuePair which work fine but in ios I used JSON, NSDictionary and also your idea but its not vorking. please help me.

Comment: which type of problem you get on server side?

Comment: Is this post is useful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427804/sending-parameters-to-php-script-in-ios

Comment: I don't have access of server but may be some parsing issue because it work well for android version.

Comment: Have you checked format of data passed from application using application like wireshark? because i believe there should not be problem in code.