# Restful with Json post

Tags: iphone, json, web-services, post

I am new to iphone technology , can any one help , i want to send a JSON DATA using POST method to server.

can any one help me by giving some simple sample application

Comment: your question is unclear. please add more content.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of `NSUrlConnection`  for this job.
SO already has a well explained [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request)
You have to set your JSON data as http Body in the `NSUrlRequest` 
There are also other kits such as ASIHTTPRequest (abandoned but used widely now also),RestKit etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrlString]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if ([m_ProductInfoDictonary objectForKey:@"TOKEN"] != nil) {
        [dict1 setObject:[mAppDelegate.m_ProductDictonary objectForKey:@"TOKEN"] forKey:@"token"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict2 setObject:[mAppDelegate.m_ProductDictonary objectForKey:@"PRODUCTNAME" ] forKey:@"title"];
    [dict2 setObject:[mAppDelegate.m_ProductDictonary objectForKey:@"DESCRIPTION" ] forKey:@"description"];
    [dict2 setObject:[mAppDelegate.m_ProductDictonary objectForKey:@"PRODUCTPRICE" ] forKey:@"price"];
    [dict2 setObject:[mAppDelegate.m_ProductDictonary objectForKey:@"ZIPCODE" ]forKey:@"zipcode"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:dict2 forKey:@"item"];
    [dict setObject:dict1 forKey:@"user"];
    //[dict setObject:dict3 forKey:@"item_images"];
    [dict1 release];
    [dict2 release];
[request setPostValue:[dict JSONRepresentation] forKey:@"item_post"];
[request setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:200];
[request setDelegate:self];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];

[request startSynchronous];
[requestUrlString release];
```