# Cannot save NSString to a .txt file on the internet

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring

txt file on my domain and I can't manage to save into it, here is my code:

```
NSString *countstring = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.DomainName.com/MyAppName/count.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        int countInt = [countstring intValue];
        NSLog(@"count string is:%i",countInt);
        int newCount = countInt + 1;
        NSLog(@"new count is: %i",newCount);
        NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",newCount];
        [newString writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.DomainName.com/MyAppName/count.txt"] atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

(I censored my domain name and app name) 
The logs are:

```
count string is:0
new count is: 1
```

which is right! But when I open the file on the domain it is still 0.
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Just imagine the impossibility of having *anything* on the internet if this worked. Everyone's content would constantly be getting hacked. =)

Comment: well its just for debugging purposes :) I'm not storing any personal data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save something to a file on the Internet from an app. You have to use server-side code to update the file.

Try using the answer here to update the file using a web service:

[iOS: how to perform a HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request)

This also requires that you write some kind of web service for you app to call, which will update the file. This is a lot more complex than what you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work like this. You can't write to this and that URL you randomly find on the web? The usual approach to this is issuing a HTTP POST request with the data and then using some server-side script for actually updating the file.

Answer (score 0):

@H2CO3 is right that usual approach is a HTTP post. I haven't tried this but writing strings to file directly should work but your URL has to be in form of `file://` In your case it's http which will not work!