# JSON posting data iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can i do the JSON post method in iOS 5,i have fetched data using NSJSONSerialization,but i don't know how to post the data to the server.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request

Comment: Try this too: http://bit.ly/PGqy6t

Comment: i have used this line to parse the json         json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];..in my project arc is enabled so i am not using json kit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check AFNetworking library http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/, available here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking, makes posting and receiving JSON data a breeze.