# iOS Integrate Sendy API Into App

Tags: ios, api, networking

I am making an iPhone app that will need to communicate with the [Sendy API](http://sendy.co/api). I *believe* that it uses some kind of JSON, but I'm not really sure, nor do I know where to start. I'm particularly interested in the `subscribe` portion of the API. **Basically, I need to know how to talk to the Sendy API from my app.**

Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    self.data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.erwaysoftware.com/sendy/subscribe"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"john@test.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"email"];
    [request setValue:@"john" forHTTPHeaderField:@"name"];
    [request setValue:@"LxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQ" forHTTPHeaderField:@"list"];
    [request setValue:@"true" forHTTPHeaderField:@"boolean"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.data setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
    [self.data appendData:d];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")
                                 message:[error localizedDescription]
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
                       otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Do anything you want with it

    NSLog(@"%@", responseText);
}
```

When the log happens, the string is empty. I know through breakpoints that the last method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the API it's all just plain text response.

Since it's a POST you can use an `NSURLConnection` to compose the request.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request) for information on formatting the response.

An alternative is to use something like [AFNetworking](http://www.afnetworking.com) or [RestKit](http://www.restkit.org) that might be a little more friendly if you're doing more work with APIs.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time with it... I've posted my code in the question.

Comment: If I send a POST request to the URL in your code it comes up blank.  Are you sure the service is set up correctly?

Comment: I really don't know... I'll do some research into it later today.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've already resolved this but in case anyone else gets stuck here (as I did) I thought I'd post what I did to get it to work.

The first thing you need to do is create a category called NSString+URLEncoding (or whatever) which is going to take your email and name fields from blah@blah.com and turn it into blah%40blah.com. I modified this from the handy blog post found [here](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios)

```
@interface NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
@end

#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"

@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)self,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                                             CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));}
@end
```

Ok so now just import NSString+URLEncoding.h and add the following code and you'll be in business. This [post](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/) helped me with this part

```
- (IBAction)submitButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stashdapp.com/sendy/subscribe"]];
[newRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[newRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString *email = @"name@domain.com";
NSString *name = @"First Lastname";
NSString *list = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&boolean=true&name=%@&list=%@", [email urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[name urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],list];

[newRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:newRequest delegate:self];
[conn start];
}
```

You still include the delegate methods which you quoted in your question.

Hope it helps someone!