# iOS login to a webservice

Tags: ios, web-services, authentication

I'm very new to iOS and I was trying to figure out how to login in a webservice.
I'am able to connect using a UIWebView to the login page but I was wondering if this could be made in a native way using UITextFields and making some kind of background request to the login page when a button is pressed, all without using UIWebView.
Could you explain me how it's done?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you didnt specify too much info about what exactly you are logging to and the api which is being used, but as a short answer, yes it is possible. you will probably be looking to use nsurl request, see this post here: [iOS: how to perform a HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-a-http-post-request)

Comment: Thank you! I was able to resolve this using the ASIHTTPRequest ;)