# How to POST with base64 image in URL

Tags: objective-c, api

I'm trying to figure out how I can do a PUT request to my backend, with in the URL a base 64 image and some other parameters.

this is the code I'm using:

```
                NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mywebservice/api/appearances/%@?name=%@&fontsize=%@&logo=%@&active=%@",app.id,app.name,app.fontsize,[app.logoimage base64EncodedString],app.active]];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                                   timeoutInterval:30.0];
                NSLog(@"de url ziet er zo uit: %@", URL);
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

                NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
                [connection start];
```

When I replace the long base 64 image string by a short random String it works.

Anyone who knows what can be the reason?

Thanks!

rendered url: http://cl.ly/0j2p1R2Q0w36

Comment: Have you tried multipart?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `POST` request as the maximum length of a URL is something like 2000 characters.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-an-http-post-request) is a good SO question which should give you clues on how to implement the `POST` request.

Comment: I guess my problem here is then that I'm using grails as the backend service, and I can't figure out how I can get the HTTP body instead of just the parameters in the POST/SAVE method.

Comment: @leke That sounds like another question you might like to ask here (or  simply search for the question as it's almost certainly already been answered).