# Converting PHP post request format in objective C

Tags: php, iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to call webservice created in PHP.The request and response is succesfull when i send this from php :

```
    $.post( 
        'http://166.178.11.18/server/xs/reliable.php', 
        {"name":value2}, // any data you want to send to the script
        function( data ){  
         $( 'body ').append( data );

        });
```

This works perfectly fine through php code but when i am trying to send it from objective C code,server is not able to receive the parameters ,response shows request for null value.
I am calling it as:

```
   NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [theRequest setValue:currentUniqueID forKey:@"name"];

  NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest  delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Do something here
}
```

But this one returns response for null ID value.

Comment: That's not how you send post parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-an-http-post-request

Comment: you want to create request like this `http://166.178.11.18/server/xs/reliable.php?name= currentUniqueID ` right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this,

```
     NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=%@",currentUniqueID];

        NSLog(@"post ==> %@", post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://166.178.11.18/server/xs/reliable.php"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        //NSLog(@" route id is :%@",postLength);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
       NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
     } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }
```

If currentUniqueID is integer than `@"name=%@"` will be `@"name=%i"`