# Programmatically enter text into input tag and programmatically "click" the submit button

Tags: ios, input, uiwebview, tags

How do I get user input and set that to the "giftcard #" and "access code" fields at this website

I then want to extract this data.

To summarize, this app will get the text that the user wants to search, fill it into the input value in the webpage, and finally retrieve the URL that is the product of searching.

Answer (score 0):

Read the source of the website. Somewhere there will be a field `form method="POST"` or `form method="GET"`

I think it will be `POST`.

If so you will need to make a post request to the website named in the `form action="http://website.de/page.php`.

Then you can do something like here : [iOS: how to perform a HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-an-http-post-request)

Comment: what if the form action isnt a website?

Comment: It looks like this: 
<form class="general payment-options last" id="NewGiftCard" name="NewGiftCard" method="post" action="GuestCheckGiftCardBalCmd">