# IOS to PHP POST parameters?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create '**Contact Us**' ViewController, which can send an e-mail , but I don't want to use the **MFMailComposeViewController** because I want to set the e-mail address which receive the message.

### So..

I tried to create a **viewController** which take the all the message data from the user and send it to a **PHP** page which will do the rest of progress, so I tried to send the parameters using **GET Method** to the **PHP** page, which is good for short parameters such as *'name'* or *'phone number'*, but I couldn't use this method for long text such as *'message content'*. So I decided to use **POST Method**, but I couldn't find a way that could send the data from my app to **PHP** using **POST Method**

I'm trying to send three **NSString** with the names (MsgTitle, MsgCity, MsgContent)

My **PHP** code

```
<?php
    $MsgTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $MsgCity = $_POST['city'];
    $MsgContent = $_POST['description'];
?>
```

I hope there is an easy way to do that, and thank you in advance ...

Comment: Did you google? Try: `objective-c php request` as search terms.

Comment: How to perform an [HTTP Post in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-an-http-post-request).

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense at all.  You said "I don't want to use the MFMailComposeViewController because I want to set the e-mail address which receive the message".  But [MFMailComposeViewController has a "`setToReceipients`" API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/setToRecipients:) that DOES allow you to set the destination e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `NSMutableURLRequest` object, set the `HTTPMethod` to `@"POST"`, put the parameters in the HTTP body as a properly formatted string — the same as GET parameters:

```
[request setHTTPBody:@"subject=foo&message=lorem%20ipsum"];
```

Send the request using `NSURLConnection` and check for an error:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = NULL;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

if (!responseData || urlResponse.statusCode != 200) {
  NSLog(@"error: %@", error); // probably want to also tell the user that the message failed
}
```